# How to pronounce "Sturm"?

Tags: mathematicians, pronunciation

The celebrated phrase "Sturm und Drang" is German. I know the pronunciation of the German noun "Sturm".

But, I would like to pronounce the French name "Sturm" of "Jacques Charles François Sturm".

Comment: Probably the same; the border shifted a few times and the people weren't nailed down either.

Comment: man the guy is not here to tell you how to say his name.

Comment: Do you mean how to pronounce it in English? Names in other languages are not always pronounced in English the same way they are originally (just think about how Paris is pronounced). For instance, I've often heard Navier in English pronounced as Nay-veer or Nah-vee-err (see http://vimeo.com/18185364), which is not like French. In English the name Chebyshev is not pronounced like it is in Russian (where the stress belongs on the final syllable).

Comment: It depends in what language you want to pronounce it. In French, a German origin name would be pronounced in the French style.

Comment: For what it’s worth, the Russian spelling in [Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BC,_%D0%96%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B0) is Жак Шарль Франсуа Штурм, implying a German pronunciation of the surname.

Comment: Thank you all. All answers and comments are interesting.
I am a non-roman-alphabet user. So, sometimes I should transcribe foreign names phonetically. I would (tentatively) write the name Sturm in German style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Charles_Francois_Sturm) says that "his family had emigrated from Strasbourg around 1760". So, *Sturm* is probably a name of German origin and is pronounced as in German.

Comment: The name is certainly German, but it seems his mother tongue was French: "in order to learn German, he attended the local Lutheran church where sermons were preached in that language".

Comment: And in Strasbourg, the family might well have spoken the Alsatian dialect rather than standard German.  I don't know whether their pronunciation of "Sturm" would differ from standard German.

Comment: Seems to be the inverse problem to how to pronounce the name of the German mathematician Lejeune Dirichlet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite agree: Strasbourg and Alsace were  part of France since the end of the 17th century. Of course it's an Alsatian name, hence from a German dialect. However, Sturm is a French mathematician, born in Geneva in 1803, and in French I always heard `stuʁm`.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, the name is likely pronounced the German way. If you still want the French pronunciation, though, it is s̪t̪yʁm using IPA phonetics.